# Clickhouse doen't work on port 8123. Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)

Tags: database, clickhouse

everyone. I have install clickhouse on Ubuntu. But when I am trying to start server:

```
sudo systemctl start clickhouse-server
```

nothing happen. Also I noticed that db doesn't listen default port 8123. For, instance commands below do not give any result:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn  | grep clickhouse
sudo netstat -tulpn  | grep 8123
```

When I try to start server 'clickhouse-client --password', I get:

```
ClickHouse client version 22.8.4.7 (official build).
Password for user (default): 
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000). (NETWORK_ERROR)
```

Clickhouse status:

```
clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big data) Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service; enabled; ve> Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-09-07> Process: 10730 ExecStart=/usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhous> Main PID: 10730 (code=exited, status=233/RUNTIME_DIRECTORY) CPU: 90ms
```

Clickhouse clickhouse-server.err.log:

```
11. _start in /usr/bin/clickhouse (version 22.8.4.7 (official build)). Will overwrite it 2022.09.07 11:42:23.694750 [ 21604 ] {} <Error> Application: DB::Exception: Caught Exception Code: 76. DB::ErrnoException: Cannot open file /var/lib/clickhouse/uuid, errno: 13, strerror: Permission denied. (CANNOT_OPEN_FILE) (version 22.8.4.7 (official build)) while writing the Server UUID file /var/lib/clickhouse/uuid
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

- `sudo systemctl status clickhouse-server`
- `sudo tail -300 /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log`
- `sudo tail -300 /var/log/clickhouse-server/stderr.log`

Comment: sudo tail -300 /var/log/clickhouse-server/stderr.log, I do not have such log file

Comment: you should update your question instead of adding comments

Comment: Thanks for advice, I updated comment. I also tried to reinstall clickhouse, doesn't help as well